# Best approach for horizontal slider CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making a slide scrolling site that goes to a specific section on button click (or scroll). The idea is on the main page when you hit a button it translateX's left or right depending on the section.

How you would lay out the CSS so that each section is inline with 100vh and 100vw. Right now it seems that in between each section theres a 100vw of empty space. The end goal is that the .main section is the first section you see on load and the can either scroll or, ideally, the buttons (you can see the onclick fuctions I'm working on) can let you traverse the site. But wont do that till later. Need to work on the css.

```css
#all-sections{
    display:inline-flex;
}
.main, .about, .professional, .fun-stuff, .blog, .contact{
height:100vh;
position: relative;
display:block;
width:100vw;
}

.main{
    background-color:white;
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.about{
    background-color:red;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.professional{
    background-color:purple;
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.fun-stuff{
    background-color:black;
    transform: translateX(+100%);
}

.blog{
    background-color:blue;
    transform: translateX(+200%);
}

.contact{
    background-color:rgb(1, 235, 21);
    transform: translateX(+300%);
}
```

```html
<section id="all-sections">
<section class="main">
<header>
<ul id="menu-list">
    <button onclick="toAbout()" id="about">About</button>
    <button onclick="toProf()" id="professional">Professional</button>
    <button onclick="toFun()" id="fun-stuff">Fun Stuff</button>
    <button onclick="toBlog()" id="blog">Blog</button>
    <button onclick="toContact()" id="contact">Contact</button>
</ul>
</header>
</section>

<section class="about"></section>

<section class="professional"></section>

<section class="fun-stuff"></section>

<section class="blog"></section>

<section class="contact"></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the positions of each section are already set to `relative`, meaning they will be positioned relative to the previous section, you could just set each section to have `left: 0` so they will start one after the other.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

#all-sections{
    display:inline-flex;
}
.main, .about, .professional, .fun-stuff, .blog, .contact{
    height:100vh;
    position: relative;
    left: 0
    display:block;
    width:100vw;
}

.main{
    background-color:white;
}

.about{
    background-color:red;
}

.professional{
    background-color:purple;
}

.fun-stuff{
    background-color:black;
}

.blog{
    background-color:blue;
}

.contact{
    background-color:rgb(1, 235, 21);
}
```

```html
<section id="all-sections">
<section class="main">
<header>
<ul id="menu-list">
    <button onclick="toAbout()" id="about">About</button>
    <button onclick="toProf()" id="professional">Professional</button>
    <button onclick="toFun()" id="fun-stuff">Fun Stuff</button>
    <button onclick="toBlog()" id="blog">Blog</button>
    <button onclick="toContact()" id="contact">Contact</button>
</ul>
</header>
</section>

<section class="about"></section>

<section class="professional"></section>

<section class="fun-stuff"></section>

<section class="blog"></section>

<section class="contact"></section>
```

If you want the navigation bar to always be visible, you could set that element specifically to `position: fixed` and it will not move as it scrolls.

```css
#menu-list {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

#all-sections{
    display:inline-flex;
}

.main, .about, .professional, .fun-stuff, .blog, .contact{
    height:100vh;
    position: relative;
    left: 0
    display:block;
    width:100vw;
}

.main{
    background-color:white;
}

.about{
    background-color:red;
}

.professional{
    background-color:purple;
}

.fun-stuff{
    background-color:black;
}

.blog{
    background-color:blue;
}

.contact{
    background-color:rgb(1, 235, 21);
}
```

```html
<section id="all-sections">
<section class="main">
<header>
<ul id="menu-list">
    <button onclick="toAbout()" id="about">About</button>
    <button onclick="toProf()" id="professional">Professional</button>
    <button onclick="toFun()" id="fun-stuff">Fun Stuff</button>
    <button onclick="toBlog()" id="blog">Blog</button>
    <button onclick="toContact()" id="contact">Contact</button>
</ul>
</header>
</section>

<section class="about"></section>

<section class="professional"></section>

<section class="fun-stuff"></section>

<section class="blog"></section>

<section class="contact"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks. what if I wanted the .main section in the middle and .professional and .about to the left and the others on the right? Was the main goal idea. Thought about reordering the sections but still creates space on the left and right.

Comment: You can't have a negative positioned element, so your best bet would be to put the `main` section after the `professional` and `about` sections, and use JS or jQuery to go to the `main` section when the window is loaded. Keep in mind traditional reading is left-to-right, hence why this isn't supported. It could be confusing to load a website and have the option to scroll both left and right.